# SQL statement only returns a single row, where it should return multiple

Tags: sql

I have database that contains data points from various sensors. These data points are taken twice a minute.

I am using the following SQL query to attempt to get two separate data points at two different times.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE TagName = 'TagName' 
  AND ("DateTime" = 'X' OR "DateTime" = 'Y')
```

I see no reason why this should not return 2 data points, one for the first date, and one for the second, but for some reason the query only returns the row for Y.

I feel like I am missing something extremely obvious.

For a bit more context, this query is used in conjuction with a python script to grab data between two dates using a specific resolution.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I believe it has something to do with the structure of the database and how it operates in terms of giving entries a time value.

It needs more investigation on my part so im going to flag this question for deletion, thanks all for you help

Comment: there is nothing technically wrong with what you wrote above... it should indeed work, so long as you have the table column names right and there actually *is* data for both those date-times... So for us to help you from here, you need to show us: table structures, and the data that causes this result. (Note: do not put this stuff into comments - edit your question and add it there)

Comment: Perhaps the row with `DateTime` value of `'X'` does not have a `TagName` value of `'TagName'`?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if that is a mistype in your question, but if not, it is probably the `"` after the `AND` part of the statement:

`AND ("DateTime" = 'X' OR "DateTime" = 'Y')`

It should be `AND (DateTime = 'X' OR DateTime = 'Y')`. Notice no quotes.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed00ba/3

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my original comment but the actual column name is "DateTime" which holds the DateTime value. Confusing I know, but I didn't design he database haha. Ill append that now.

Comment: Yes, if the `DateTime` is the column name, that doesn't require any quotes, you don't need to wrap it in anything or backticks, but not quotes. You will only need the quotes for the string values.

Comment: You are right. Surprisingly enough, I just tested it and it works either way.

Comment: `AND (DateTime = 'X' OR DateTime = 'Y')` is wrong, because DateTime is a DataType but in the Question they are FieldName, then should to write as `AND ("DateTime" = 'X' OR "DateTime" = 'Y')`